# C# Class project - need help calculating perimeter

Tags: c#, class

Consider the following project:

Create a new Windows Forms Application project and change its Name to MyRectangle. Create a class named Rectangle. Add a private integer variable named _height, and another private integer variable named _width. Add accessors for both variables, calling them Height and Width. Have the accessors read and write the _height and _width variables. Add a public method named GetArea() that returns the area of the rectangle, and another named GetPerimeter() that returns the perimeter of the rectangle. Use the code shown below to define these methods.

```
public int GetArea()
  {
   return (_width * _height);
   }

   public int GetPerimeter()
  {
   return ((2 * _width) + (2 * _height));
   }
```

Modify the public MyRectangle() method to create an instance of your Rectangle class. Use the Height accessor to set the rectangle height to 6, and the Width accessor to set the rectangle width to 8. Call the GetArea() and GetPerimeter() methods, and output the results to the Console. 
**---End of project instructions----**

I created the class.cs as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;    

namespace MyRectangle
{
    internal class Rectangle
    {
        // ** Properties **
        private int _height = 0;
        private int _width = 0;

        // ** Accessors for Height**
    public int Height
        {
            set
            {
                _height = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _height;
            }
        }

        // ** Accessors for Width **
    public int Width
        {
            set
            {
                _width = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _width;
            }
        }
    public int GetArea()
    {
        return (_width * _height);
    }

    public int GetPerimeter()
    {
        return ((2 * _width) + (2 * _height));
    }
    }
}
```

I think I got the class file right, but beyond that I am completely stuck.

Comment: Hi, Second part of the code is the class.cs file i did which was the goal of the training... i got stuck calling the class from the form code... by the way this is not an official "credit school work" just a side training i am taking to learn about C#.. thanks for the comments

Answer (score 2):

You develop the Rectangle class correctly, remaining reuse it

```
MyRectangle.Rectangle _Rectangle = new MyRectangle.Rectangle();
_Rectangle.Height = 6;
_Rectangle.Width = 8;
int _RectangleArea = _Rectangle.GetArea();
int _RectanglePerimeter = _Rectangle.GetPerimeter();
```

Comment: Many Thank you for your help ...

"the world is much better because of peps like you!"